# Does a deleted answer still count as the first answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, enlightened-badge

Some badges like the [Enlightened](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) requires one to be the first to answer. I have cases where my answer was accepted like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517612/prevent-rounding-off-of-timestamp-in-mysql/25517809#25517809), and the answer previous to mine was deleted, thus making my answer the only one.

**Is a deleted answer counted as the first answer?**

Does it prevents a question for awarding the "first to answer" type of badges?

I understand that some answers might be related to experience, but I would be inclined to accept an answer that provide an official documented reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it does not. Deleted answer's don't count.

For example, I got the Enlightened badge for this answer even though the deleted answer came first.

[Need help in mod 1000000007 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any reference that officially confirms it? I wasn't able to find any :(

Comment: wonder how the system would handle case if answer gets undeleted

Comment: @Evandro Not that I'm aware of it. But I've seen at least 2 or 3 cases of it.

Comment: @gnat If the badge is already awarded you keep it. I'm pretty sure the script awards it at the time it checks. So if the answer gets deleted/undeleted a bunch of time, it only has to be deleted at the point the script runs.

Comment: @Mysticial I think your print is enough evidence. Thank you.

Comment: @gnat Badges are never taken back. Once awarded you have them forever. Unlike privileges, loosing rep means a loss of privileges if you fall under the threshold.

Comment: I recalled seeing this question a while back, but didn't recall the answer. I was planning on posting an answer based on my recent experience with getting the badge a *long* time after any activity on that post, because the first answer was deleted today....though I see you beat me to it. Have some reps (+1) :)