# Backlog hat not awarded after requirements met

Tags: support, winter-bash-2020

I answered a question ~380 days old and both my answer and the question have a positive score. Requirements were met a few hours ago.

The requirements for Backlog:

> Answer a question from 2019 or earlier that does not have any answers. Both question and answer must have a positive score.

While a question could have a deleted answer, that I cannot see due to < 10k reputation, which prevents this hat from being awarded as it is currently coded, in no practical way is a deleted answer an answer... See [this accepted answer on how the Enlightened badge is awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238652/275704) for a similar situation.

Here is the question: [How to refresh a blazor sub/child component within a main/parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226890/how-to-refresh-a-blazor-sub-child-component-within-a-main-parent-component/65472990).

Comment: I wonder if there's a deleted answer there that's messing with this. Can a >10k SO user confirm?

Comment: @Spevacus yes, there is a deleted answer. Self deleted last year, 0 score.

Answer (score 1):

Full [description](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/backlog) is:

> Answer a question from 2019 or earlier that does not have any answers. Both question and answer must have a positive score.

And as per [rene's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358910/backlog-hat-not-awarded-after-requirements-met#comment1198235_358910), there is a deleted answer present there, making you not eligible for that hat.

Comment: To be fair, this might as well be a bug in the hat. E.g. for the Enlightened badge an older (but deleted) answer on the same question doesn't matter.

Comment: @Glorfindel then only CM can confirm it

Comment: I endorse this answer

Comment: @YaakovEllis Possible to update the hat description?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Can you please explain why the team decided to implement it this way? How are <10k users supposed to know that there is a deleted answer before attempting to earn the hat? Are they expected to ask a 10k+ user in order to check beforehand? I'll add that the badges that check for first answers ignore deleted answers, so why was it decided to code this hat differently?