# Missing Enlightened badge after 24 hours

Tags: bug, badges

#### 4/16/21

For [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183938/62294) over on rpg.se, I have met the requirements for the enlightened badge for more than 24 hours. The answer was accepted at 23:21 on 4/14, and it hit a score of 10 at 10:36 on 4/15 (this is easily verified by doing the counting at [my reputation tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/62294/thomas-markov?tab=reputation)), and it is the only answer (no deleted answers).

I know "where's my enlightened badge" questions happen often and the answer is always "give it some time", but I have *always* gotten my enlightened badges in at most 3-4 hours after hitting the requirements, so 24 hours without the badge seems highly irregular.

Per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/674198), I am posting this bug report:

> Under extremely rare circumstances, it may be possible for the badge criteria to be faulty. To confirm if this is still the case, wait 24 hours for any scripts to run, then carefully read the exact criteria here and check to see if you still continue to meet them, before filing a bug.

[image]

#### 4/21/21

It has happened again, causing me to question the hypothesis that we've just been unlucky, so I'll document it here. Maybe rpg.se is just *really* unlucky on the badge script.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183441/62294) was marked accepted with a score of 12 at 17:18 on 4/19/2021, and the Enlightened badge for it was received at 01:25 on 4/21/21, approximately 32 hours after becoming eligible.

It was highly irregular the first time it happened, so it is *exceedingly* irregular for it to happen twice in a week.

Comment: Are there no deleted answers on the post?

Comment: @Luuklag That is correct, there are no deleted answers.

Comment: @Luuklag it's not obvious, [but that doesn't matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238651/295232).

Comment: Ah okay, so that doesn't even matter :) Thanks for clarifying @Glorfindel

Comment: @Glorfindel Theoretically, someone could have posted an answer before me, deleted it, then undeleted right before the script ran each time, but that isn't feasible for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Luuklag you're welcome, I've appended the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

I was finally awarded the Enlightened badge at 14:55 on 4/16, 28.3 hour after becoming eligible. From [animuson♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) in comments:

> Based on the query, your answer is eligible to be awarded the badge whenever it runs next. The "within 24 hours" thing is true in most cases, but not technically correct anymore. All the badge queries used to run on set schedules of "every this many minutes" but a while ago we changed that to just have one schedule and all badge queries have a percentage chance of running each time. Seems the site has just been unlucky in getting it to run (no awards since early April 15 despite 5 people becoming eligible over the past day). I don't see anything else broken.

Comment: Where is that comment? It's perhaps useful to link to in the FAQ, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Glorfindel It seems it was deleted.