# Don't show the "Congratulations - you earned [badge]" notification in the badge tracker until the system has actually awarded the badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

In one's own user profile page's activity tab, on the badge tracker, if someone meets the criteria to earn the badge they're tracking, the page will show "Congratulations - you've earned [badge name]". This message is loaded live at the time one loads their profile, meaning that it will show the message even if the system's job queue hasn't actually awarded the badge yet.

This message is technically incorrect, however, if the script that runs badges hasn't awarded the user the badge yet. It serves to leave an incorrect impression on the user, as when they check their overall badges, it won't be listed, so they may incorrectly think that the badge was revoked for whatever reason. (There have been [reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363319/377214) about badge awards taking very long recently.)

It also leaves an incorrect impression if the user meets the criteria at the time they load their profile, but ceases to meet the criteria by the time the script can run and award them the badge. It can make users think that the system revokes badges if the user no longer meets badge criteria, which has been clarified multiple times to not be the case. The badge was simply never awarded, but the message in the profile incorrectly says that it was awarded, so it *looks* like it was awarded and removed.

(I actually had the latter case happen to me once - I posted my 50th and final qualifying answer for the Refiner badge, and loaded up my profile, and was shown "Congratulations - you've earned Refiner", but the question was closed before the script to award the badge ran - answers to closed questions don't count for the badge - so I didn't earn it. I was tripped up by the message and was about to post a bug report, but checked my answer history and saw that it had dipped to 49 as a result of the question closure.)

Can the "Congratulations - you've earned [badge name]" message in the user profile not be shown until the badge script has run and actually awarded the badge? Or, alternatively, show a message to wait 24 hours for the badge to be added to your profile?

Comment: ... or be replaced with "You've qualified for the badge - please wait up to 24 hours for the badge to be awarded"? Otherwise we'll get many bug reports from users with a full progress bar who wonder if they somehow don't qualify (I'm looking at you, Curious badge ...)